# Get the accuracy of model on prediciton

Tags: python, keras

l want to get the accuracy of my model predicting the labels of `x_test`

```
   from __future__ import print_function
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense
    import keras
    import numpy as np
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(2000, input_dim=3072, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(66, activation='softmax'))
    model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=128)
    scores = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train)
    print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Now l want to get accuracy on prediction

```
predictions = model.predict(x_test)
```

l tried :

```
  print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], predictions*100))
```

l got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-262-edbcf292f31c> in <module>()
----> 1 print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], predictions*100))

TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.ndarray
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.predict` produces a `numpy.array` which is something completely different from `float`. You might try to print that using `print(predictions)` but using formatted string with `float` absolutely won't work in this case. Try:

```
print("\n%s:" % (model.metrics_names[1]))
print(100 * predictions)
```

or

```
print("\n%s: %s" % (model.metrics_names[1], np.array_str(predictions*100)))
```

or if you have only one case in `x_test`:

```
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], predictions[0]*100))
```

Comment: predictions is of shape (2000,50). l want to get max probability of each row. l tried predictions.max() but it returns the max of  the whole 2d array however l 'm looking for a 1D vector of 2000 where each value represents the max in a row

Comment: Try `max(axis=1)`.